# Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a custom renderer for ProgressBar so I can change its color. My classes are below:

```
public class ColorProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public static BindableProperty BarColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create( "BarColor", typeof( Color ), typeof( ProgressBar ), Constants.ORANGE   );

    public Color BarColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue( BarColorProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( BarColorProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

Then, in the MyApp.UWP project, I have:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(ColorProgressBar), typeof(ProgressBarRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.UWP
{
    public class ColorProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
    {
        public ColorProgressBarRenderer() {}

        protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e )
        {
            base.OnElementChanged( e );

            if ( e.NewElement == null )
                return;

            if ( Control != null )
                UpdateBarColor();
        }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged( sender, e );

        if ( e.PropertyName == ColorProgressBar.BarColorProperty.PropertyName )
        {
            UpdateBarColor();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateBarColor()
    {
        var element = Element as ColorProgressBar;
        var color = Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb( (byte)255, (byte)247, (byte)137, (byte)30 );
        var brush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush( color );
        Control.Foreground = brush;
    }
}
}
```

However, I get the error in the subject line along with `Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Xaml.dll'` when building. I suspect it has something to do with setting the color and brush, but I'm not sure how to get the correct class otherwise.

I just wanted to change the color :/

EDIT: I added the System.Xaml.dll assembly, and now I get an error in App.xaml when building: `Object reference is not set to an instance of an object`. Is there a conflict between Xamarin and System.Xaml.dll?

Comment: System.Xaml is for WPF, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml is for Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Jason I don't understand why it was complaining about not being able to resolve System.Xaml.dll